# Django Admin class to auto-populate user field

Tags: python, django, admin, auto-populate

I am trying to populate the field 'owner' in the my NoteForm. I read in documentation that I need to use the Admin for that.But i still get this error : note_note.owner_id may not be NULL. Need help. Code:

forms.py:

```
class NoteForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Note    
    fields = ('title','body')
```

models.py:

```
class Note(models.Model): 
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
    cr_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=False)
```

admin.py

```
class NoteAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
         obj = form.save(commit=False)
         obj.owner = request.user
         obj.save()

    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
            instances = formset.save(commit=False)
        for instance in instances:
             instance.user = request.user
             instance.save()
        else:
             fromset.save_m2m()


admin.site.register(Note, Noteadmin)
```

views.py:

```
 def create(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = NoteForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

        return HttpResponceRedirect('/notes/all')


    else:
       form = NoteForm()

args = {}
args.update(csrf(request))

args['form'] = form

return render_to_response('create_note.html', args)
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand the point of Admin over here. From the code, what I understood is you creating a simple django form for your site and getting the error on form submission. If that's case, the solution is quiet easy. This error is generated because you are try to save a record in your `Note` model without any reference to `User`. As there's a db constraint on the foreign key field, it raises the error. Solution is easy, just add `owner` to the list of fields in the form or modify the `save` method to assign an owner to the note. If you'll use the first option, the user will be able to see and select the owner. And if you want to pre-populate that particular field, pass [initial value to the form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values).

Comment: Thank you for posting . I think that is one of the most stupid thing in Django framework.This totally crazy. I log on as UserA , i go to create a new note and i need to decide which user in creating this post.So i will see thousands of username in the list. Have you where seen that in any website? Of course you need to note to be auto-populated by the user that is logged in.This all happens cause in django there is sessions for user.

Comment: I read the documentation but i dint understand.Can you help me . Something like that ? owner = NoteForm(initial={'username': 'instance'}, auto_id=False) in model Note ?

Comment: You only want to pre-populate username? Have a look [FormView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#formview). It has a function `get_initial()` which is used by `Form` to get initial values for fields. It returns a dictionary. In that dict, add `{'username': self.request.user.username}` and your form will be initialized with the required username.