# Django template image won't load (repost)

Tags: python, html, css, django

Image wan't load.I see o broken image icon.I use the static tag. I also tried giving the absolute path and never worked.I used the alt tag but still i can only see the broken image icon. Is the tag correct what else should i try ??? The images is in static\images\logo.png

base.html

```
{% load static %} {# loads static tag #}



<div id="header">
    {% block header %}
       <img src="{% static 'images/logo.png' %}" alt="alternative text"  />
    {% endblock %}
</div>
```

setting.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = ''

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATIC_ROOT = ''

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = ('assets','C:\Users\@#@#@#@#@\workspace\project\static'),
```

Comment: I tried on mozilla and not chrome and i can now see the alternative text. I guess the image is still not found

Comment: SO *specifically* forbids duplicates. Marking your post as a repost is guaranteed to get it closed (although ten out of ten for honesty, I guess).

Comment: @Daniel Roseman . yes it is. Its a update of the last post. No answer was found so i reposted it. Any help ?

Comment: i now provide the code from settings file. They better delete the old one

Answer (score 1):

Try either

`<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/logo.png" alt="alternative text" />`

or fixing your quotes

`<img src="{% static 'images/logo.png' %}" alt="alternative text"  />`

and fixing your settings

`STATICFILES_DIRS = ('assets', r'C:\Users\@#@#@#@#@\workspace\project\static'),`

or

`STATICFILES_DIRS = ('assets','C:\\Users\\@#@#@#@#@\\workspace\\project\\static'),`

Comment: Nothing. I've really tried everything. nothing works for me......        Request Method:GET .....
Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/images/logo.png

Comment: Try setting `STATIC_ROOT` and running `collectstatic`

Comment: seeting.py : # Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/var/www/example.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = ''..............When i edit this setting the css in meshed up.

Comment: Did you run `python manage.py collectstatic` after changing it?

Comment: maybe i didnt understand. I ve read the documentation before.What i am suppose to write in STATIC_ROOT=" " ? . The directory that says in dajngo docs is the same directory with STATICFILES_DIRS ,simply because that's the directory of the static files. Although i copied the same directory in root , but nothing happens.

Comment: No, STATIC_ROOT is a directory that django uses to collect all static files to. You dont put anything in here, it gets autopopulated when you run the `collectstatic` command. STATICFILES_DIRS holds extra directories which contain static files for your project. The files in these directories get copied to STATIC_ROOT.

Comment: So why did you say " Try setting STATIC_ROOT " ??? My files are in project/static and in project/assets. I ve run collectstatic several times. what else ?

Comment: The problem is you don't understand how STATIC_ROOT and STATICFILES_DIRS work. Read the documentation again, it's not that difficult. However, your last comment has revealed your problem:  You need to add the `assets` directory to your `STATICFILES_DIRS`. `STATICFILES_DIRS = ('C:\\Users\\@#@#@#@#@\\workspace\\project\\assets', 'C:\\Users\\@#@#@#@#@\\workspace\\project\\static')`

Comment: THANK YOU !!! so much , i really don't understand why this was necessary. I thought assets are just files collected from the website ,but the files that are "up" in the website are the files in static folder. Why where you the only one to see this ?

Comment: Because in both your posts, you never mentioned that you were putting the static files in a different folder (other than `'C:\\Users\\@#@#@#@#@\\workspace\\project\\static'`), and what you had set the STATICFILES_DIRS to was valid.

Comment: But that's not true . I always had the files is project/static folder. The files where only duplicated to the assets folder when run the command collectstatic. where i am suppose to load the image from ? why am not available to load it from static folder ??? No i see that the image is loaded from assets folder. Is that correct ???

Comment: Can you help me with a more serious problem i have?   : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20286144/django-admin-class-to-auto-populate-user-field .

Answer (score 0):

It's worth asking whether or not you've used Django's `collectstatic` method after including the image in your assets folder.

Comment: yes sir i ve done this. the files are in assets folder

Comment: have you tried using a relative path for STATICFILES_DIRS?  try using ('assets', 'static')...that works for me

Comment: STATICFILES_DIRS = (('assets','static')). Nothing changes

Comment: are you able to see the image if you don't use the django static method and simply put in the relative path to the image in the src attribute?

Comment: Like this : <img src="C:\Users\#%#%#%\Desktop\logo.png" alt="alt2" /> ???? Nothing again . Actually that is interesting . how is that possible?

Comment: <img src="/pathToFileInAssetsFolderFromRootOfProj" />

Comment: <img src="C:\Users\##%#%#\workspace\project\assets\images\logo.png" alt="alt3" />  ??? Do you realize that it can't even load a image from desktop? How is it not possible load a image from absolute path?